# Which filetypes supported by Windows Media Player allow the embedding of DRM?

Tags: windows-media-player

Hopefully a relatively simple question... but one that I haven't been able to find the ansewr to!

Out of all the filetypes that Windows Media Player supports, which allow publishers to add DRM to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you only asking for audio formats, or for video formats as well? Out of all the audio formats currently supported by WMP (Windows Media Audio, WAV, MP3, FLAC, MPEG-4), only Windows Media Audio (aka WMA) has support for DRM built into the format and player.

Comment: Thank you. :) Video too if that's ok - a complete list would be great!

Comment: Regarding video, I think that only ASF, WMV, and DVR-MS support DRM. The full list of file types supported by WMP is [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316992/file-types-supported-by-windows-media-player) (without any mention of DRM support unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : All of them.

The reason is that the DRM is not embedded - the files are rather encrypted
and can only be played through an application that decrypts them, usually
using a license that is either built into the application, or furnished as
a license file, or through an Internet subscription.

All file types can be encrypted for DRM, although a decrypting-player application
might be limited to playing only some file-types.

For more information, see Wikipedia
[Digital rights management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management).